# Z-index html issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following css for 2 divs on a single page.

```
.transaction{
    position: fixed;
    left: 31.5%;
    top: 34%;
}

.managed{
    position: fixed;
    left:17.5%;
    top:45%;
}
```

This is used for positioning the divs, each div has the following classes and css

```
.teaser{
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #7b98ac;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
    -moz-opacity: 0.89;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.89;
    opacity: 0.89;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=89);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=89);
    filter: alpha(opacity=89);
    z-index: -10;
}

.actual {
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow: auto;
    word-wrap: normal;
    display: none;
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #e1261c;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
    -moz-opacity: 0.89;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.89;
    opacity: 0.89;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=89);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=89);
    filter: alpha(opacity=89);
}
```

i need the .actual div to have a higher z-index and float above the .teaser (HTML BELOW)

```
<div class="transaction pop">
    <div class="shape"><img src="./images/shape.png" alt="multi media solutions" /></div>
    <div class="text" >
        <article class="teaser">
            <label >test</label>
        </article>

        <article class="actual">
            <label>test</label>
            <br><br>
            <p>test</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="managed pop">
    <div class="shape"><img src="./images/shape.png" alt="multi media solutions" /></div>
    <div class="text" >
        <article class="teaser">
            <label >test</label>
        </article>

        <article class="actual">
            <label>test</label>
            <br><br>
            <p>test</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery does everything else - I've attached my JS below if it helps

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*POP up text script*/
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".pop").mouseover(function() {
            var src = $(this).find(".shape img").attr("src","./images/shapehover.png");
            $(this).attr("src", src);

            $(this).find(".teaser").hide();
            $(this).find(".actual").css("margin-top", "-80%");             
            $(this).find(".actual").show();
        }).mouseout(function() { 
            var src = $(this).find(".shape img").attr("src","./images/shape.png");
            $(this).attr("src", src);
            $(this).find(".teaser").show();
            $(this).find(".actual").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

my js fiddle - [jsfiddle.net/Pheonix/tET94/3](http://jsfiddle.net/Pheonix/tET94/3)

Comment: Add a JSFiddle please

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z3PPq/

Comment: so then, what's your problem exactly ? What result do you *want* ? What result do you *get* ? What did you tried ?

Comment: Fiddle with images: http://jsfiddle.net/StephanWagner/ZssxL/ I also don't see what youd like to achieve

Comment: do you want the the div with "test" in it to be on top of the shape ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Pheonix/tET94/3/ - test1 on hover should be above test 11...

Answer (score 1):

you have to add the `position` proprety to there class and set it to either `absolute` , `relative` or `fixed` according to your need  or else the proprety `z-index` wont work.

Comment: my js fiddle - jsfiddle.net/Pheonix/tET94/3 - test1 on hover should be above test 11...